# get data from database that falls in between 2 dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I have a data base which has various columns among which are the columns "Effective Date" and "Termination Date"

The situation is before adding a record I need to make sure that there is no overlapping record for the given set of Effective and Termination dates. How could I implement this? I am building the app with MVC using LINQ.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check any of records startDate and TerminationDate are in your new record's start and termination date or not, you can do this with linq:

```
bool overlap = db.Records.Any(x=>(x.TerminationDate >= givenRecord.StartDate 
                  && x.StartDate <= givenRecord.TerminationDate) ||
                  (x.TerminationDate <= givenRecord.TerminationDate 
                  && x.StartDate >= givenRecord.StartDate));
```

Comment: @Habib.OSU, Also your approach is like mine, but I just used dot notation syntax and I just considered that both start and end dates of records and new record.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from t in dbContext.table
             where t.EffectiveDate.Value <= yourDate && 
             t.TerminationDate.Value >= youDate
             select t).Count();
if(result > 0)
{
//Overlap
}
```